# docopt interprets any -v as version

Tags: python, command-line-interface, docopt

I am creating a cli with docopt and have the following issue (I'll bring in examples from their naval_fate example cli)

`naval-fate --version` or `naval-fate -v` will return the cli version but when try doing let's say `naval-fate ship -v` for a different purpose, it automatically returns the same result as the first two commands.

Is there a way to prevent docopt from doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent docopt from parsing `-v` as a special option by simply mention it yourself in the docstring, as an option. For example, suppose you would like to use `-v` for verbosity:

```
!/usr/bin/python
"""
Usage: ./ [options]

Options:
-v  show verbose printing
"""
from docopt import docopt

arguments = docopt(__doc__)
if arguments["-v"] == True:
    print "A verbose message"
```

In this case, running the script with no parameters will do nothing, while running it with `-v` will generate the string "A verbose message"